# Adding splash screen to cocoa App in swift

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, splash-screen

I am using below code to add splash but seeing a crash to close after 2 sec

```
@IBOutlet var customView: NSView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let splashScreen : NSImageView

   let rect : NSRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 421, 231)
   let splashWindow : NSWindow = NSWindow.init(contentRect: rect, styleMask: .borderless, backing: .buffered, defer: true)
    splashScreen = NSImageView.init(frame: rect)
    splashScreen.imageScaling = .NSScaleToFit
    splashScreen.image = NSImage.init(named: "splashScreen.jpg")
    customView.addSubview(splashScreen)

    let xPos :CGFloat = splashWindow.screen!.frame.width / 2 - splashWindow.frame.width / 2
    let yPos : CGFloat = splashWindow.screen!.frame.width / 2 - splashWindow.frame.width / 2
     splashWindow.setFrame(NSRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: splashWindow.frame.width, height: splashWindow.frame.height), display: true)
    sleep(2)
```

splashWindow.close()

The crash is occurring at

```
splashWindow.close()
```

I also tried replacing

```
splashWindow.perform(#selector(splashWindow.close), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)
```

But no luck, it will be of great help if you can point me to some tutorial to add splash screen to cocoa app using swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this simple NSWindow creation code trigger an autorelease pool crash on shutdown under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345378/why-does-this-simple-nswindow-creation-code-trigger-an-autorelease-pool-crash-on)

Comment: use a delayed NSTimer + have own splashviewcontroller and xyviewcontroller. Use property contentViewController of NSWindowController to swap the viewControllers. All this should be done in windowController. Best solution would be NSTimer + 2 windowControllers (one in tabless...).   PS: NEVER EVER create a new window in viewDidLoad.